# 3D plot is giving empty box,

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

```html
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.special import kv #calling bassel func
from scipy.special import iv #calling bassel func
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.misc import derivative
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

#######################################################
def B(x):
 #bassel func~~~~~
 #first 
 v0 = 0  #order of bessel func
 K0 = kv(v0, r/x) #BESSEL Function
 I0 = iv(v0, r/x) #BESSEL Function
 #~~~second 
 v1 = 1  #order of bessel func
 K1 = kv(v1, r/x) #BESSEL Function
 I1 = iv(v1, r/x) #BESSEL Function
 c = (I0*K0)-(I1*K1)
 return c
#######################################################

Ms = 3e+11
ms1 = 1e11
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mh = np.linspace(9.5,11.5,20)
mhalo = 10**((-0.0210331*mh**5) + (1.042316*mh**4) - (20.553*mh**3) + (201.74*mh**2) - (985.821*mh) + (1929.48))
Mh = mhalo
#~ r = 6 #in Kpc
r = np.linspace(0.01,6,20) #in Kpc

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#virial radius:
Rv = 259.3*(Mh/1e12)**(1/3)
#Disk mass halo mass relation:
Md = 2.3e10*(Mh/Ms)**(3.1)/(1+(Mh/Ms)**(2.2))
#disk length to halo mass relation:
Rd = 10**(0.633+(0.379*np.log10(Md/ms1)) + (0.069*(np.log10(Md/ms1))**2))
#optical radius:
Ropt = 3.2*Rd
#Burkert-halo central density:
rho0 = 10**(-23.5153 - 0.918*(Md/ms1)**(0.308))
#burket core radius:
r0 = 10**(0.66+0.58*(np.log10(Mh/ms1)))
#burket halo density:
rho = rho0*r0**3/((r+r0)*((r**2)+(r0**2)))
#burket Halo mass:
Mhr = (1.48e31*1.6*4*rho0*r0**3)*(np.log(1+(r/r0))- np.arctan(r/r0) + 0.5*(np.log(1+(r/r0)**2)))
#Halo velocity:
Vh = 658.1*(Mhr/(ms1*r))**0.5
#disk velocity:
x = 2*Rd
Vd = 658.1*((0.5*Md/(ms1*Rd))**0.5)*(r/Rd)*B(x)**0.5

#total velocity:
vurc = ((Vd**2) + (Vh**2))**0.5

XX = r
YY = vurc
ZZ = mh

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
img = ax.plot_surface(XX, YY, ZZ)
plt.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=15)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=15)
plt.tick_params(axis='z', which='major', labelsize=15)
ax.set_xlabel('R/Ropt', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('V/Vopt', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_zlabel('log(M_vir)', fontsize = 15)
plt.show()
```

In this code below, 3D plotting commands are not working neither giving any errors, just plotting the empty box. While, my all arrays are of same size. Could anyone hlep me out.

Comment: Have you tried checking the values of your arrays? Frequently this happens because you are trying to plot an array of `nan` values.

Comment: yes, I checked, each value in the array is finite.

Comment: For a surface plot you need all input arrays to be 2D arrays, not 1D. Please refer to [the official example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html).

Comment: I just tried to use `[XX,YY,ZZ]=np.meshgrid(r,vurc,mh)` but got _ValueError: too many values to unpack_ even though all arrays have the same shape.